# How can I check an array for an entire object (or at least 2 key-value pairs) [in reactjs]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm trying to increase the quantity count of an existing object in my shopping cart instead of adding it again. Objects look like this:

```
{
id: 2​​,
name: "Squash Supreme",
selectedSize: "38",
price: 75,
quantity: 1
}
```

With `.includes()` I tried to verify if the exact object already exists in the array, but couldn't. Tumbled over `.find()` `.some()` etc. but none of the examples took two key-value pairs.

**I need to check if an object with two identical key-value pairs (id and selectedSize) is already present.**

Any suggestions? (I'm using react, with functional components, Array is in an `useState.`)

After that I can tackle the increment functionality ;)
**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: *"...but none of the examples took two key-value pairs."* That doesn't matter, what the `find` callback does is completely up to you. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35398031/157247) to the linked dupetarget is `myArray.find(x => x.id === '45').foo;`. In your case, it would be `const entry = myArray.find(x => x.id === theId && x.selectedSize == theSize);`

Comment: There surely may be certain suggestions ***to help you progress with your current attempt*** if sample array (to play with) along with desired result were provided. Until neither of those were given, odds aren't too high.

Comment: Thanks Crowder! I knew there was an easy solution :)